# Why OnDataChange() is still called even there is no data in database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use this code to check if there are particular data in my DB:

```
  mDatabase.child("TempTransaction").child(MainActivity.User.getID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.child("state").getValue().equals("Pending")) {

                    mTransactionExist = true;

                } else {
                    mTransactionExist = false;
                }

            }
```

I first thought that the ValueEventListener (onDataChange) should never be executed if I have no TempTransaction with that particular child in my json db. turns out that even I changed the child "TempTransaction" to any string like "asdasfasfx" or "xcvcxwasd" the onDataChange still called. 
why is that?

Is there any firebase default keyword or something to make it skip if no particular child is found in the db structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ValueEventListener` will always "immediately" be called with the current value at the location. If there is no current value at the location, it will be called with an empty snapshot.

There is no way to change this behavior, but you can detect the empty snapshot with:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
```

Comment: In my case onDataChange() is still called about 7-10 times even when i put ref.removeEventListener(this); inside  onDataChange()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method. Adds a listener for a single change in the data at a particular location. This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at that location.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but this not really answering my question, and in my case i need to keep listening not just once.  and actually the question would remain the same even if i replace my addValueEventListener to listenerForSingleValueEvent.

Comment: Another approch will be to remove the listener like this: `databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);` when you consider that is no more needed to listen. Also you can use `databaseReference.keepSynced(false);` to stop that reference for being synced. More than that, you can use `goOffline()` method, that shuts down your connection to the Firebase Database backend until goOnline() is called.

Comment: i only need explanation about the behavior of the listener. why it would listen to a non existing child, the calling of onDataChange() at non existing data confused me.

Comment: The listener will listen on the exact reference that you indicate. To stop doing that, you can use one of the methods explained above.